# Is there a dry peppermint flavoring?

Tags: flavor

I want to make a peppermint cocoa mix but I can only find peppermint extract in liquid form at my grocery store.  Is there such a thing as a dry peppermint flavoring thats natural?

Comment: If you’re okay with it being sweetened, you can crush up peppermint candies.  But it may shorten the shelflike, as it will try to absorb moisture from the air

Comment: ...must... resist... asking "why would you do such a horrible thing to poor innocent cocoa"... Whoops. :)

Comment: @Marti I tried it with a shot of creme de menthe recently.  Not as good as amaretto, but still nice

Comment: no affiliation, but this is what I got when Googling "peppermint flavor powder": https://www.naturesflavors.com/products/peppermint-flavor-powder-natural . There were a bunch of other results as well.

Comment: I don't know if this is what you're looking for, [https://www.amazon.com/Bulksupplements-Peppermint-Extract-Powder-grams/dp/B01MCZK7P2/] but it popped right up searching Amazon so I'm thinking there are other purveyors selling various versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dried peppermint leaves exist. Probably a bit more roughage than you want in cocoa, but if you want natural, that's the stuff.

I would expect that mixing oil of peppermint or peppermint extract with the sugar (if normal hot cocoa with sugar) would result in a still-dry mixture at normal rates of oil/extract and sugar for hot cocoa. Sugar free the dried leaves are my best bet other than Joe's suggestion in a comment on the question if you could find sugar-free mint candies.

Answer (score 2):

Use peppermint candy.

1. Crush up the candy and mix it into the dry cocoa mix---you don't have to crush it very finely, as it will dissolve into the cocoa when you mix it up.  You might reduce the amount of sugar you add to the mixture (e.g. if you add one ounce crushed peppermint candy, reduce the sugar by one ounce—peppermint candies are usually almost 100% sugar).
2. Use a candy cane or peppermint candy stick as a stirrer when you serve the cocoa, or drop in one or two of those little round peppermint candies when you make the cocoa.  In either case, the candy typically dissolves pretty quickly.

Comment: This is an excellent idea as well, I might give this a shot if I can find some basic peppermint candies without additional additives.

Comment: @binarylegit Adding the phrase "all natural" to a search will often find things with fewer ingredients.  For example, "[all natural peppermint stirrers](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=all+natural+peppermint+sticks)" seems to bring up a bunch of useful results.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to find dry mint flavoring, yes. It might take some searching though.

Menthol itself is a crystal. If all else fails, you may try getting that. It will be a pain to dose, but it will cover your requirements.

Another possibility is that specialized spice/extract producers or molecular gastronomy providers may carry mint aroma on a maltodextrine carrier powder. I haven't had it for mint, but I have used orange flavoring of this type, and it worked well. If you can't find it, it may be easier to find maltodextrine separately and mint essential oil (or even mint extract) and make your own.

Comment: A Google search for "peppermint flavor powder" got me a number of reasonable-looking options